# overwrite object property Javascript

Tags: javascript

I basically having hard times understanding why I cannot overwrite an object property when using inheritance from another object, it goes like this.

```
var Person = function(firstName, lastName) {
  this.firstName = firstName;
  this.lastName = lastName;
};

Object.defineProperties(Person.prototype, {
  sayHi : {
   value :function() {
     return "Hi there";
   },
   enumerable : true,
   writable : true
  },
 fullName : {
   get : function() {
    return this.firstName + " " + this.lastName;  
   },
   enumerable : true
  }                      
});


var createEmployee = function(firstName, lastName, ocupation) {
  var employee = new Person(firstName, lastName);
  employee.ocupation = ocupation;  

 Object.defineProperty(employee, "sayHi", {
   sayHi : {
    value : function() {
     return "Hey I am " + this.firstName;
    }
   }
 });

 return employee;
};

var janeDoe = createEmployee('Jane', 'Doe', 'Actress');
```

So, accoding to what I understand, I should overwrite the sayHi property on the employee object, however, I get it as undefined.

Could please some1 show me money?

here is the [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/andresmijares/jzMGu/)

Best Regards.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just realized the answer I gave was bad.

You don't need the name inside the object there.

```
Object.defineProperty(employee, "sayHi", {
sayHi : {//<- don't need this.
    value : function() {
    return "Hey I am " + this.firstName;
  }
 }//<- or this.
});
```

Answer (score 25):

You could use the outdated `Object.defineProperty()` or the `Object.assign()`. However, there's a cleaner, more modern solution to this.

Simply do:

```
objectName = {...objectName, property: "newvalue"};
// or
objectName = {property: "newvalue", ...objectName};
```

the difference between the two is that the first will overwrite the property named `property`, while the second will create a new property called `property` and assign a value, however, it won't overwrite it if it already exists.

Take a look at [JS spread syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) for more info.

Such could also be done for setting your prototype:

```
Person.prototype = {...Person.prototype, sayHi: _=>"Hi there!"};
```

Comment: Thank u! But this answer came like 5 years later... where were u when i needed u? Ah?? :@

Comment: lol! This stuff is relatively new... So even if I had seen this sooner it'd likely not have been as easy as it is now... Anyways, I hope it helps in the future!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
 Object.defineProperty(employee, "sayHi", {
   value: "Hey I am " + employee.firstName
 });
```

Also, Mozilla's explanation on [Object.defineProperty()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperty) is quite excellent, you should check it out.